# MediaPlayer can't play video from Url with wrong header content-type

Tags: uwp

We are trying to play video files from remote servers and when the response header content-type is "application/octet-stream" instead of any of the common types such as "video/mp4" the file is not reproduced.

Our code basically uses MediaSource.CreateFromUri(), for these situations we are trying to change to MediaSource.CreateFromStream(tempStream,"video/mp4") but this method requires a IRandomAccessStream. Using response stream.AsRandomAccessStream() does not work because it complains about "Can't perform seek operations in the stream"

We tried to use a derived class to use RangeHeaderValue to collect chunks of the file from the remote server and pass this to MediaSource.CreateFromStream(), this works but the performance is very poor as on every call of the MediaSource a new http request is made and the video hangs. Any way to request range headers from those servers without recreating the request on every loop?

Is there any way to create some kind of temp memory stream from that url that does not block the player nor fills the device memory and can be consumed by MediaSource.CreateFromStream(tempStream,"video/mp4")?, another ideas to play that video url with wrong content type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I known there is no such api for `MediaPlayerElement ` playing the `application/octet-stream` directly. For your scenario, the better way is that converted `application/octet-stream`  content-type to `video/mp4` in your remote servers.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that we can't control those servers and we can't ask for a content type change so that's why we are searching for a workaround or alternative to prebuffer that thing or so. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: What webhost provider do you use? I face same issue.